# Print linkedlist nodes

Tags: python

I would like to first create my linkedlist and then print the list list nodes. I tried a few methods but always getting a wrong output.

Below is my code:

```
class node:
    def __init__(self, dataVal=None):
        self.dataVal = dataVal
        self.nextVal = None

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.headVal = None

    def printList(self):
        printVal = self.headVal
        while printVal is not None:
            print(printVal.dataVal)
            printVal = printVal.nextVal

    def insertEnd(self, n_node):
        new_node = node(n_node)
        if self.headVal is None:
            self.headVal = node(new_node)
        else:
            end = self.headVal
            while(end.nextVal):
                end = end.nextVal
            end.nextVal = new_node

def createList(array, n):
    linkedList = LinkedList()
    for i in range(n):
        linkedList.insertEnd(array[i])
    return linkedList

if __name__=='__main__':
    t = 2
    n = [5,6]
    array = [[1,2,3,4,5], [2,3,6,7,5,1]]
    for i in range(t):        
        head = createList(array[i], n[i])
        print(head.printList())
```

My current output:

```
<__main__.node object at 0x0000026152300400>
2
3
4
5
None
<__main__.node object at 0x00000261523257B8>
3
6
7
5
1
None
```

My expected should be:

```
<__main__.node object at 0x0000026152300400>
1
2
3
4
5

<__main__.node object at 0x00000261523257B8>
2
3
6
7
5
1
```

I do not know why the "None" appears and also why the object printed as well. Can anyone help?

Comment: In `insertEnd`, change `self.headVal = node(new_node)` to `self.headVal = new_node`.  You're creating a node-within-a-node.

Comment: I see. thank you so much sir.

Comment: And also do you know why is there a none?

Comment: Yes, the reason is that you're doing `print(head.printList())`.  But `printList` itself prints the list, and implicitly returns `None`.  You should just call it.  But instead, you're printing the return value.  Just change it to:  `head.printList()`

Comment: Thank you sir, now I get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the print to get rid of `None`. Change

```
print(head.printList())
```

to

```
head.printList()
```

Also

```
if self.headVal is None:
```

is equivalent to but more pythonic

```
if not self.headVal:
```